# How to disable all Console Modes in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to port an application I wrote on linux to windows but I cant seem to figure out how to set the console to "raw mode" with `SetConsoleMode()`. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? The linked page has a reference to the example.

Comment: See also [High-Level Console Modes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/high-level-console-modes): *When all are enabled, the application is said to be in "cooked" mode, which means that most of the processing is handled for the application. When all are disabled, the application is in "raw" mode, which means that input is unfiltered and any processing is left to the application.*